# how to query External Managed Account Output

Tags: apex, soql, salesforcedx, query

I'm referring to [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_responses_external_managed_account_output.htm) link and i want to find the AccountId of an external Managed account. I'm not sure how to query this. Or is there any way I can implement this to find the Account Id? Please do help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the context in which you are operating, there are two services available that return that information.

- Experience Cloud: [Experience Cloud Sites Externally Managed Accounts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_communities_externally_managed_accounts.htm?q=External%20Managed%20Account%20Output)
- Commerce Cloud: [Commerce Webstore Externally Managed Accounts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_commerce_webstore_external_managed_accounts.htm?q=External%20Managed%20Account%20Output)

Rather than using these APIs you can also utilise the ExternalManagedAccount class within Apex to provide the same details. You can find these documented here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_ConnectAPI_ExternalManagedAccount_static_methods.htm

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So in case I'd like to get all the external managed accounts following the implementation by using ExternalManagedAccount class, i only do `ExternalManagedAccount.getExternalManagedAccounts(webstoreId)` and pass in my webstoreId in the place yes? Or is there any other way i need to do to get all the external managed accounts? Do let me know. Thanks again.

Comment: Hey, yep that should provide you all of the external accounts for that webstore.